# how to retrieve images from .mdf sql database in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to retrieve the images I saved into my .mdf database. I need the code to enable me pull the data and display them in a `pictureBox`.

How do I retrieve images from the .mdf database and display them in a VB application with a `pictureBox`?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
Dim path As String = (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Application.StartupPath, Len(Application.StartupPath) - 9))
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=[Server Name];AttachDbFilename=" & _
        path & "Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand

cmd = New SqlCommand("select photo from Information where name='image1'", con)
Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
        ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    End Using
End If
```